# Using Python to call MATLAB scripts in different directories results in Undefined function 'x'' for input arguments of type 'int64'

Tags: python, matlab, anaconda, python-3.7

Currently I am building a testing framework that uses MATLAB and Python scripts. I have one main script say 'MainFramework.py' that calls and passes arguments to a Class say 'MainClass_X.py' that calls and passes arguments to a function say 'x.py' that itself calls and passes arguments to 'x.m'.

the MainFramework.py has the following format of code:

```
from MainClass_X import MainClass_X 
arg1="something1"
arg2="something2"
Test=MainClass_X(arg1,arg2)
Test.run()
```

the MainClass_X.py has the following format of code:

```
from x import x
class MainClass_X(object):
 def __init__(self,paramater1,parameter2):
   self.paramater1=paramater1
   self.paramater2=paramater2
 def run(self):
   x(self.paramater1,self.paramater2)
```

the function x.py has the following format of code:

```
import matlab.engine
def x(arg1,arg2):
  eng=matlab.engine.start_matlab()
  eng.x(arg1,arg2,nargout=0)
```

When MainFramework.py, MainClass_X.py, x.py and x.m scripts are all in the same directory the scripts work as designed. However, as soon as I move MainFramework.py into a parent directory, the script gives me the following MATLAB error: Undefined function 'x'' for input arguments of type 'int64'.

For better understanding, please find below the structure of the directories:

```
__directory1__
   MainFramework.py
__directory1/subdirectory1__
   MainClass_X.py
   x.py
   x.m
```

I have double checked the path to make sure that MainFramework.py calls on the right MainClass_X.py, and I am sure that it does.

I am using MATLAB 2020a and Python 3.7 and Anaconda3 and Spyder as an IDLE.

Is there any way to get around this error. It is very important for the purpose of the task that the python scripts are in different directories.

Comment: have you tried renaming the x.m to some other name say new_func.m and call eng.new_func(arg1, arg2 , nargout=0)  inside x.py ?

Comment: Yes, I have. However, still the same error message

Comment: since you are using anaconda , these links might help https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/415682-how-to-run-m-file-in-python  and check how many values your script is returning https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-script-and-function-from-python.html  exclude nargout=0 and try as well

Comment: I have taken a look at both of those links. it is no help as they only touch on how to run MATLAB script using python which is not the reason I am getting the error above.

Comment: Also, excluding or modifying nargout will not help as the MATLAB script is not returning any output to the python script.

Comment: I think the `x.m` file is not on the Matlab path when you start the engine from another working directory, so you'll have to add the path of your matlab files using `eng.addpath(r'<thepath>',nargout=0)` when starting the engine

Comment: Hello thank you for your input. However, eng.addpath does not mitigate the error.

Comment: getting rid of x.py and adding eng.addpath(r'<thepath>',nargout=0) before calling calling eng.x(arg1,arg2,nargout=0) in MainClass_X @rinkert, Thank you!!!!